# Sessions information not sticking around. Node.js, Express, Passport & Ajax

Tags: ajax, node.js, session, oauth-2.0, passport.js

I'm trying to get this working but I'm lost. I want to redirect a person on success or on failure to the provided URLs.

I'm setting the URLs into the session on the server when they request an authentication.

```
        // Setup redirect URLs
        if (typeof(req.session) !== 'undefined') {
            if (typeof(req.session.passURL) == 'undefined') {
                req.session.passURL = '';
            }
            if (typeof(req.session.failURL) == 'undefined') {
                req.session.failURL = '';
            }
            if (typeof(req.query.passURL) != 'undefined') {
                req.session.passURL = req.query.passURL;
            }
            if (typeof(req.query.failURL) != 'undefined') {
                req.session.failURL = req.query.failURL;
            }
        } else {
            console.log('No Session?!?');
        }
```

Then I request the auth from the oAuth provider:

```
                console.log(req.session);
                req.app.passport.use(googleStrategy);
                req.app.passport.authenticate('google', {
                    scope: [
                        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
                        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'
                    ]
                })(req, res);
```

The log of the session above gives me:

```
{ cookie:
   { path: '/',
     _expires: null,
     originalMaxAge: null,
     httpOnly: true,
     proxy: true,
     secure: true,
     key: 'cookie.sid' },
  passport: {},
  passURL: 'google.com',
  failURL: '' }
```

When google is done and sends the user back to the callback URL I do this:

```
                console.log(req.session);
                req.app.passport.authenticate('google', {
                    failureRedirect: req.session.failURL
                })(req, res, function(err) {
                    if (err) {
                        req.app.lib.util.returnJSON(req, res, 200, err);
                    } else {
                        getUser(req, req.session.passport.user, function () {
                            req.session.passport = null;
                            if (typeof(req.session.passURL) != 'undefined' && req.session.passURL != '') {
                                res.redirect(req.session.passURL);
                            } else {
                                req.app.lib.util.returnJSON(req, res, 200, JSON.stringify(req.session.user));
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
```

On log session in the oAuth callback I get:

```
{ cookie:
   { path: '/',
     _expires: null,
     originalMaxAge: null,
     httpOnly: true,
     proxy: true,
     secure: true,
     key: 'cookie.sid' },
  passport: {} }
```

According to Chrome this is the process the client sees:

[image]
[image]

Node seems to be setup for sessions properly:

```
                    app.use(express.session({
                        store: new MongoStore({db: connection}),
                        cookie: {
                            proxy: true,
                            maxAge: null,
                            secure: true,
                            key: 'cookie.sid'
                        },
                        secret: app.get('cookie_secret')
                     }));
            app.use(app.passport.initialize());
            app.use(app.passport.session());
            app.use(app.router);
```

I don't understand why the session gets lost.